# Forgot the name of a game I saw once - like Ars Magica, but more freeform

Tags: product-identification

About four years ago I ran across a tabletop system I really liked, but neglected to save the file. It had a magic system rather like Ars Magica's - you picked a form and an element and paid a cost to cast them.

The reason I know it's not Ars Magica is that "Creo Temporis/Create Time" was possible: there was a very memorable example of making a "solid time" sword. I'm pretty sure Space was also a valid element.

There was something like a breakdown of each element into levels - you'd add some number (to the difficulty? to the level requirements?) in order to get more complex effects. I'm fairly sure this isn't Mage, because I remember an 8 showing up in those numbers and WoD only ever goes up to ten in rare occasions. I'm afraid I don't remember the dice used, though I'm fairly sure it wasn't d10.

Does this sound familiar to anybody?

Comment: Could you include any similar game systems you know that this game is not? For instance, you could be describing any of the WOD Mage games. Any other information like the year you played the game in, the setting of the story - any mechanics - like the dice used. This would all be much more helpful.

Comment: I added as much as I remember, but this was four years ago and the magic system was the most memorable thing about it.

Comment: Oh, if it helps, I do remember it seeming a tad obscure of a game to me, and that the setting was very like Ars Magica - medieval fantasy with wizard's towers.

Comment: You mention "saving the file", implying you encountered this online. Could it have been a homebrew addition to Ars Magica?

Comment: Yeah, it was a pdf... and it could have been, perhaps, except I'm pretty sure the mechanics are all wrong. I'll need to reread the AM ruleset, but I'm pretty sure the mechanics don't quite match.

Comment: You mention it is "like Ars Magica" But you don't say what the similarities are. Can you give examples of the game, and how it was similar to Ars Magica? (Could it perhaps be a different version? homebrew content? or simply a setting as opposed to the system?)

Comment: Nope. Never played it and never ran it; I read its file once, thought "huh, that's interesting" and put it aside, and now I want to find it. I thought it was a different version at first, but as far as I can tell, the impossibility of time magic has been a thing going all the way back to the first edition. Homebrew content is a possibility, though it's kind of hard to tell since it'll be very hard to find again if it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. *Elements of Magic*, a d20 expansion.